# React Code automatically restructured after made some changes and save changes

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, web

I am working on a React project using a Visual Studio Code. when I press `Ctrl+S` in the Visual Studio Code to save file. It removes all the ReactJS formatting or scatter all the code in the file.

**My Code Before saving**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Hello andi
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**My Code Looks like after made changes or on save with `ctrl` + `s`**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    return ( <
        div className = "App" >
        <
        header className = "App-header" >
        <
        img src = { logo }
        className = "App-logo"
        alt = "logo" / >
        <
        p >
        Hello andi <
        /p> <
        a className = "App-link"
        href = "https://reactjs.org"
        target = "_blank"
        rel = "noopener noreferrer" >
        Learn React <
        /a> <
        /header> <
        /div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

along with VS Code Shows me error of enclosing tag help me please

Comment: You might have some plugin installed in the vscode for formatiing, try using prettier plugin and do the same process again, it shall format your code nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to uninstall the formatting plugin in your VS-Code.

***or you should try it if code is scattered after made some change or on save:***

Press `Ctrl` + `<` and type `format on save` and Check if "Format On Save" is disabled
[image]